# Excel web access data ( graphs) is showing gray color on SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, web-services, excel-services

I am using "Excel Web Access" Web Parts to show the excel graphs in my MOSS2007 setup. I have multiple team sites under one site-collection. Excel web access is fine for all the team sites but , its showing only gray color for just one site. I tried to upload new excel sheet with different graphs but still it shows the same gray color.

Any help would be really appreciated. I will provide more details if needed.

Thanks,
Umesh

Comment: is there custom css or custom masterpage with this other site?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to resolve my issue: I ran "SharePoint Technologies and Configuration Wizard" on my SharePoint servers and rebooted them. That resolved my issue. 
[Excel Web Access Graphs Showing Gray Color](http://windowsadminblog.blogspot.in/2012/12/excel-web-access-graphs-showing-gray.html).

Comment: I have added the information to your answer and include the link just for reference (especially as the solution on the blog is shorter than the URL ;-) ).